# how to read URL and Print in Servlet in java

Tags: java, servlets

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getRequestURL());
    System.out.println("Received Value: "+request.getRequestURL());
    Utils.getDataFromFeedbackLink(request.getContextPath());        
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();      
    pw.println("<html><body>");  
    pw.println("Welcome to servlet"+request.getRequestURL());  
    pw.println("</body></html>");   
    pw.close();  

}
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>SubmitFeedbackServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.techjini.tfs.servlets.SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submitfeedback</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

this is my Code of servlet get method :
i want to print what ever request URL will be Like http://localhost:8080/TechJiniFeedbackSystem/submitfeedback/Hello servlet

then this URL should Print in my Consle i have used getContextPath and getRequestURL but non of these printing http://localhost:8080/TechJiniFeedbackSystem/submitfeedback/Hello servlet

please suggest me where am doing wrong or suggest me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

It's incredible easy: you must use **getRequestURL** from **HttpServletRequest** in your Servlet in doGet method

or for more info you can use this methods: getServletPath(), getContextPath and etc.

read more in specification:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#getRequestURL()

Comment: nothing Print even page not loading http://localhost:8080/TechJiniFeedbackSystem/submitfeedback/hello wgen i use given URL

Comment: see this, PrintWriter is Evil, but for showcase example is enough, or use println in console http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/05/java-servlet-get-request-url.html